# Error message not displaying in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to edit some data after a `POST` in CodeIgniter.

The problem is when I make an edit I want to show a message that tells me the edit is done. I tried to do the following, but no message is displayed. Why?

**Controller**

```
function edit($id = 0) {

    $this->load->model('Event_Model');

    if ($id > 0) {
        $this->data['eventinfo'] = $this->Event_Model->getInfo($id);
    }
    $this->data['pagetitle'] = "Edit";
    $this->data['formID'] = $this->uri->segment(2)."-".$this->uri->segment(3);

    $this->template->build('admin/events/add',$this->data); 
}

function do_edit() {
    $this->load->model('Event_Model');
    $id = $this->input->post('hID');
    $data = array(
       'ev_text' => $this->input->post('ev_text'),
       'ev_pic' => $this->input->post('ev_pic'),
    );
    $this->Event_Model->update($id, $data);

    $this->data['success'] = "Done";
    $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
    $this->template->build('admin/events/add',$this->data);     
}
```

**Model**

```
function update($id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('ev_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('events', $data); 
}
```

**View** (where I want the message)

```
<?php
    if (isset($success)) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success normal-alert" style="display: block;">
            <p><span class="ico-text ico-alert-success" ></span><?= $success; ?></p>
        </div>
<?php
    }

    if (isset($errors)) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-error normal-alert" style="display: block;">
            <div>
                <span class="ico-text ico-alert-error"></span>

                <?php if (count($errors) > 0) { ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo "<li>$error</li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </ul>

                <?php } ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php  }  ?>
```

and the second error, update data with picture not work, its get me error in dubg that call me the `$_FILES['choose-file']['name']` not define

Comment: are you referring to php errors or the error message from this form

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Controller

```
function do_edit() {
    $this->load->model('Event_Model');
    $id = $this->input->post('hID');
    $data = array(
       'ev_text' => $this->input->post('ev_text'),
       'ev_pic' => $this->input->post('ev_pic'),
    );
    $result = $this->Event_Model->update($id, $data);

    if($result) {
        $this->data['success'] = "Done";
        $this->template->build('admin/events/add',$this->data);    
    }


    $this->data['errors'] = $this->errors;
    $this->template->build('admin/events/add',$this->data);     
}
```

Model:

```
function update($id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('ev_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('events', $data); 
   return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: its same thing no display any message